# How to mark property as nullable ("type | null") in Reinforced.Typings?

Tags: reinforced-typings

Reinforced.Typings has `ForceNullable` argument on `[TsProperty]` attribute but it generates optional property and my API returns literal `null` (do not omit the property or set it to `undefined`).

For example with `[TsProperty(ForceNullable = true)]` `field:boolean` becomes `field?:boolean` and I want it to be `field:boolean | null`.

Is it possible with Reinforced.Typings to achieve this?

I don't want to use workaround like `[TsProperty(Type = "boolean | null")]`, I want the c# typename to ts typename be handled by standard Reinforced.Typings logic, just add `| null` to resulted type.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable value types are easy. Reference types would require a Visitor at the very least, as you would have to use fairly complex reflection to see if it was nullable.

But for bool like your example:

```
builder.SubstituteGeneric(typeof(Nullable<>),(t, r) => new RtSimpleTypeName($"{r.ResolveTypeName(t.GenericTypeArguments.First())} | null"));
```